# add space between JFrame and JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, border, jpanel

how I can add space between JFrame and a JPanel inserts into this JFrame? I would insert space in the way that the elements inside the JPanel didn't appear too near at the JFrame

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set the JPanel's border with an EmptyBorder with appropriate parameters.

i.e.,

```
// caveat: code not tested
myPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
```

If the JPanel already has a border, then you can either use a compound border or wrap the JPanel in another JPanel, say using BorderLayout and in the BorderLayout.CENTER position, and give the wrapper JPanel an empty border.

Comment: For 'inner' panels that are going inside other panels, another way to introduce space is by providing arguments to the constructor of the parent panel layout.  Layouts often have a constructor that allows the horizontal & vertical spacing between components to be specified.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the GridBagLayout and setBounds for components? the Components will stay at the position you want.

Here an example:                                                           `

```
'import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.*;
 public class set_Components_where_i_want {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(null);
        //make new Components 
        JButton b1 = new JButton("One");
        JButton b2 = new JButton("Two");
        JButton b3 = new JButton("Three");
        //add Components first
        frame.add(b1);
        frame.add(b2);
        frame.add(b3);
        //get frame inserts 
        Insets insets = frame.getInsets();
        Dimension size = b1.getPreferredSize();
        //set position here
        b1.setBounds(50 + insets.left, 10 + insets.top,
                 size.width, size.height);
        size = b2.getPreferredSize();
        b2.setBounds(110 + insets.left, 80 + insets.top,
                 size.width, size.height);
        size = b3.getPreferredSize();
        b3.setBounds(300 + insets.left, 60 + insets.top,
                 size.width + 100, size.height + 40);
        //set size for the frame so it can contain all Components
        frame.setSize(600 + insets.left + insets.right,
                  250 + insets.top + insets.bottom);
        // make the frame be visible
        frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

}`